# PHP array returns null

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a html form with a button on which there is a onclick event

```
    <form id = "abc" action = "xyz.php" method = "post">
      <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit" 
            id="submitButton" onclick = "Function()">
     </form>
```

In the JS code, I am trying to post a value of a textbox and trying to get the array from the PHP through json_encode.

```
var valueToSend = $('#textbox').val();
var imagesReturned = new Array();
$.ajax({
        url: "xyz.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: valueToSend,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(result) {        
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

And here is my PHP code,

```
        if(isset($_POST['valueToSend'])) 
        {
            $searchValues = explode(' ',$_POST['valueToSend']);
           // Some processing here
            echo (json_encode($responseArray));

        }
```

When I alert the data, I get null, What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `$responseArray` contain?

Comment: Its an array of strings.. For example, it contains abc,xyz,pqr etc.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the line that you use `parseJSON` and see if `result` is the expected value.

Comment: Does your script use any custom buffering?

Comment: You don't need `var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);` in your callback. It's already parsed. On the other hand, your JSON response from PHP will always be empty. You'll never send the proper response because it'll contain invalid data.

Comment: You don't need to parseJSON the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the PHP code.

I removed the check,  if(isset($_POST['valueToSend'])) and its working...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is within your Ajax request, the `data` key expects a key/value pair, not just a value.

What you're looking for is something similar to the following:

```
var valueToSend = {
  'valueToSend': $('#textbox').val()
}
```

In addition, you're setting the `dataType` key to `json`, so there is no need to pass the data variable through parseJSON. As such, the `success` function only needs to be declared as follows:

```
'success': function(result) {
  alert(result);
}
```

Comment: Also note that since you are setting `dataType:"json"`, you don't need to parse the response, jQuery will do that for you such that you can work with the result object directly.

Comment: you're absolutely right, i'll update. thanks for catching that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var valueToSend = $('#textbox').val();
var imagesReturned = new Array();
$.ajax({
        url: "xyz.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"valueToSend":valueToSend},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(result) {        
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

correct the format of `data` in ajax

Comment: If I change data to   data: {valueToSend:valueToSend},
The functions returns error, it doesn't go in the success function.

Answer (score 1):

data field of yours look suspicious to me

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "xyz.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{valueToSend:valueToSend},
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(result) {        
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the data field doesn't work, it goes inside the error than success function, if i send key : value pair.. If I send just the value its success with null response!

Comment: It does not alert anything, If I add code for Error : function, It goes inside that.